# Iterate inside subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a situation where i need to iterate a condition based on where clause input, wonder how it can be done.

The background is, in one storage unit, it consists of several tanks, each tank has it own tank dip measured status, with different last measured date, how can i get the latest dip value of particular date ?

Example:

```
Tank A having last measured date (EndDate) as 01 Feb 2015.
Tank B having last measured date (EndDate) as 31 Jan 2015.
Tank B having last measured date (EndDate) as 17 Feb 2015.
Tank C having last measured date (EndDate) as 18 Feb 2015.
```

Table structure:

```
Tanks| DipDaytime| Volume| EndDate
A, 28 Jan 2015 8pm, 1000, 01 Feb 2015
B, 30 Jan 2015 5pm, 2000, 31 Jan 2015 
B, 01 Feb 2015 5pm, 2500, 17 Feb 2015
C, 01 Feb 2015 3pm, 3000, 18 Feb 2015
```

The expected output would be:

```
For 31 Jan 2015:
A, 28 Jan 2015 8pm, 1000, 01 Feb 2015
B, 30 Jan 2015 5pm, 2000, 31 Jan 2015 

For 18 Feb 2015:
A, 28 Jan 2015 8pm, 1000, 01 Feb 2015
B, 01 Feb 2015 5pm, 2500, 17 Feb 2015 
C, 01 Feb 2015 3pm, 3000, 18 Feb 2015
```

I able to come out something like this:

```
SELECT ts.Tanks, ts.DipDaytime, ts.EndDate , ts.Volume
FROM   table ts
WHERE  ts.EndDate =     
(SELECT MAX(ts2.EndDate ) FROM table ts2
                      WHERE ts2.Tanks =  ts.Tanks
                      AND ts2.EndDate <= '17.02.2014')
```

The problem is i need to change the **17.01.2014** everytime i need a different result for a particular date, also i cannot display the **17.01.2014** as part of the query result because it is not part of the table.

How can i have it in a dynamic way where i only need to provide a date range, says from 01.02.2014 to 28.02.2014, to get the complete result? and a temp column which showing the reporting date?

The end result will then be :

```
For 31 Jan 2015:
Tank | DipDaytime| Volume| EndDate, ReportDate
A, 28 Jan 2015 8pm, 1000, 01 Feb 2015, 31 Jan 2015
B, 30 Jan 2015 5pm, 2000, 31 Jan 2015, 31 Jan 2015 

For 18 Feb 2015:
Tank | DipDaytime| Volume| EndDate, ReportDate
A, 28 Jan 2015 8pm, 1000, 01 Feb 2015, 18 Feb 2015
B, 01 Feb 2015 5pm, 2500, 17 Feb 2015, 18 Feb 2015 
C, 01 Feb 2015 3pm, 3000, 18 Feb 2015, 18 Feb 2015
```

Appreciated if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: why Tank A is appearing in both the cases?

Comment: @SagarJoon: because there is no change in tank A between 31.01 and 18.02?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to filter on the latest row per `(Tank)` group.  Using a subquery trick you can use a constant for both filtering and displaying:

```
select  *
from    (
cross join
        (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by tank
                    order by EndDate desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Tanks
        cross join
                (
                select  '17.02.2014' as report_date
                from    dual
                ) pars
        where   EndDate <= report_date
        ) numbered_rows
where   rn = 1 -- Latest row per tank
```

A better way to use the constant would be to pass it as a parameter to the query.  In Oracle, parameters start with a semicolon, like `:report_date`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
with report_dates as
(
  select to_date('31 Jan 2015', 'dd Mon yyyy') report_date from dual
  union all
  select to_date('18 Feb 2015', 'dd Mon yyyy') report_date from dual
)
select t.tanks, d.report_date,
       max(t.dipdaytime) keep (dense_rank last order by t.enddate) DipDaytime,
       max(t.volume) keep (dense_rank last order by t.enddate) volume,
       max(t.enddate) enddate
from table t, report_dates d
where t.dipdaytime <= d.report_date
group by t.tanks, d.report_date
order by d.report_date, t.tanks
;
```

This gives:

```
    TANKS   VOLUME  REPORT_DATE DIPDAYTIME  ENDDATE
1   A   1000    31-janv.-2015   28-janv.-2015   01-févr.-2015
2   B   2000    31-janv.-2015   30-janv.-2015   31-janv.-2015
3   A   1000    18-févr.-2015   28-janv.-2015   01-févr.-2015
4   B   2500    18-févr.-2015   01-févr.-2015   17-févr.-2015
5   C   3000    18-févr.-2015   01-févr.-2015   18-févr.-2015
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use a slight modification to your query -- define the list of dates you want and then use that list multiple times in the query:

```
with rd as (
      select date '2015-01-31' as ReportDate from dual
      union all
      select date '2015-02-18' from dual
    )
select rd.ReportDate, t.*
from table t cross join
     rd
where t.dipdaytime = (select max(t2.dipdaytime)
                      from table t2
                      where t2.tank = t.tank and
                            t2.dipdaytime <= rd.ReportDate
                     );
```

This is using a correlated subquery to find the maximum `dipdaytime` for each tank before any given date.

Answer (score 0):

This query gives results for selected period. You have to define starting report date and last date in first subquery (`dates`).

```
with dates as (
  select to_date('2015-02-15') + level - 1 tdate 
    from dual
    connect by to_date('2015-02-15') + level - 1 <= '2015-02-18'),
tanks as (
  select * 
    from (
      select tdate, tanks, dipdaytime, volume, enddate
          row_number() over (partition by tanks, tdate order by enddate desc) rn
        from dates
        left join ts on ts.enddate <= dates.tdate)
    where rn = 1)
select tdate, tanks, dipdaytime, volume
  from tanks
  order by tdate, tanks


TDATE       TANKS      DIPDAYTIME      VOLUME
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------
2015-02-15  A          2015-01-28        1000
2015-02-15  B          2015-01-30        2000
2015-02-16  A          2015-01-28        1000
2015-02-16  B          2015-01-30        2000
2015-02-17  A          2015-01-28        1000
2015-02-17  B          2015-02-01        2500
2015-02-18  A          2015-01-28        1000
2015-02-18  B          2015-02-01        2500
2015-02-18  C          2015-02-01        3000

9 rows selected
```

Query below selects data for each tank in separate columns, so you have one row for each date from report period.

```
with dates as (
  select to_date('2015-02-15') + level - 1 tdate 
    from dual
    connect by to_date('2015-02-15') + level - 1 <= '2015-02-18'),
tanks as (
  select * 
    from (
      select tdate, tanks, dipdaytime, volume, enddate,
          row_number() over (partition by tanks, tdate order by enddate desc) rn
        from dates
        left join ts on ts.enddate <= dates.tdate)
    where rn = 1)
select dates.tdate,
    ta.dipdaytime a_ddt, ta.volume a_vol, ta.enddate a_end,
    tb.dipdaytime b_ddt, tb.volume b_vol, tb.enddate b_end,
    tc.dipdaytime c_ddt, tc.volume c_vol, tc.enddate c_end
  from dates
    left join tanks ta on ta.tdate = dates.tdate and ta.tanks = 'A'
    left join tanks tb on tb.tdate = dates.tdate and tb.tanks = 'B'
    left join tanks tc on tc.tdate = dates.tdate and tc.tanks = 'C'
  order by tdate
```

Results:

```
TDATE       A_DDT            A_VOL A_END       B_DDT            B_VOL B_END       C_DDT            C_VOL C_END
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------
2015-02-15  2015-01-28        1000 2015-02-01  2015-01-30        2000 2015-01-31                         
2015-02-16  2015-01-28        1000 2015-02-01  2015-01-30        2000 2015-01-31                         
2015-02-17  2015-01-28        1000 2015-02-01  2015-02-01        2500 2015-02-17                         
2015-02-18  2015-01-28        1000 2015-02-01  2015-02-01        2500 2015-02-17  2015-02-01        3000 2015-02-18
```